# Copying an Android Project Folder is Not a FULL Backup?

Tags: android, eclipse, workspace

Several weeks ago I took a snapshot of my Android project by simply copying the entire folder (Windows 7) to a network share.

A few weeks later, I wanted to build that snapshot in a **new** (and different) workspace. So I:

1. Created an empty folder for the
   workspace,
2. Switched Eclipse to it,
3. Then used [File > Import...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5019929/eclipse-restore-missing-projects/5020199#5020199) to copy
   that snapshot to the workspace.

I was then surprised to find errors in the project - errors that weren't there before I copied it over to the network share.

The first symptom was that only the last file in the project had multiple errors. I "fixed" that by entering into Eclipse (again!) Android's SDK location:

`Windows > Preferences > Android > SDK Location: C:\android-sdk-windows`

This resulted in numerous files now having errors, with the following hint at the console:

`Android requires .class compatibility set to 5.0. Please fix project properties.`

I fixed that by hovering over `@override` and selecting the `Change workspace compliance and JRE to 1.5` balloon suggestion. This is strange because I checked `Windows > Preferences > Java > Compiler > Compiler compliance level:` and it was 1.6 before - Doesn't 1.6 include 1.5?

I was then left with only two errors stemming from `@Override`s that shouldn't really be there (for methods implementing interface). So I removed them and now all is fine and the project builds and runs perfectly as before.

All nice and dandy but I was very surprised by the fact that I actually had to change *anything* in Eclipse, not to mention that I eventually ended up modifying the original source code (deleting `@override`s only) to get it build - source code that had no complaints whatsoever weeks ago!

What could possibly explain this? Isn't copying an Android project folder a true **full** backup?

Being baffled by this discovery, I examined the workspace folder, using my beloved Emacs, and discovered that there is a hidden subdirectory named `.metadata`. This is probably where the secret lies.

My questions now are:

1. Does Eclipse store additional
   information about the workspace
   elsewhere?
2. What is a good approach to make
   Android projects more independent,
   as in "fully backup-able"?
3. Is there any use for the
   `.metadata/.log` file? Can I safely
   delete it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had those errors too when imported a project. If I'm remembering correctly, helped right-clicking in project name and selecting Android Tools -> Fix project properties...

After that errors disappeared.

> “Android requires .class compatibility
>   set to 5.0. Please fix project
>   properties.” What’s this? It’s the
>   error I received after cloning a
>   repository and trying to import it
>   into Eclipse. There is reasonably
>   little information online about this,
>   couple discussions on mailing lists
>   but I figured I would write a post on
>   the solution to this.
>
> After importing the project to your
>   workspace, you’ve received the error.
>   So what you need to do next is to
>   right click on the project -> Android
>   Tools -> Fix Project Properties. Now
>   this alone won’t fix the problem, you
>   need to restart Eclipse after this.
>   After that try building the project
>   again and it should work successfully
>   this time (unless you have bugs in the
>   code itself, I did).

Comment: Thanks +1 for bringing Right-click > `Android Tools > Fix project properties` to my attention. I have never used it before.

Comment: Right-click > `Android Tools > Fix project properties` works like magic! (but only after correcting the missing `Windows > Preferences > Android > SDK Location: C:\android-sdk-windows`).

Comment: my problem was still not solved yet i re-imported the project and its solved now

Answer (score 2):

1. I've found that Eclipse's metadata is stored, as you found, in the **./metadata** folder of your workspace. I do not believe there are any additional folders but I will double check.
2. The best way to do a back up of the android project if you are using eclipse is to export it by right clicking the project, selecting **export** and exporting it as an archive, file system, etc. That way you can be sure you've backed it up in a way that Eclipse knows how to handle it.
3. Rather than delete it, why not make a copy of it first? **Edit**: I would also take a look at running `eclipse.exe -clean` in the command terminal. That may be more useful than manually deleting the .metadata folder.

Comment: Thanks +1. In regard to answer #3, I was referring to the `.log` **file**, not the .metadata folder.

Comment: Export to file system produces the **same exact result** as copying the entire folder.

Comment: [eclipse.exe -clean](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t61566.html) doesn't get rid of anything in the .log file. In fact, running `eclipse.exe -clean` increased it... :)

Comment: The .log file is there if you just want to take a look at all the errors eclipse likes to throw, I don't see any harm in deleting it. Eclipse will more than likely create a new one. As for -clean, I believe it clears out any caches Eclipse has built up. It won't delete the log file but it should tidy the application up a little.

Comment: In response to **it produces the same exact result**, 1. Better safe than sorry. instead of importing the project as you did earlier, did you try "File" -> "new" -> "Android Project" -> "Create Project From Existing Source" then point it to your backed up project?

Comment: I normally agree with "better safe than sorry" but in this particular case I need to *understand* why. Importing the project from an exported version produced the same exact results. There really isn't any difference.

Comment: If there is no different, I personally have done no comparison between exporting and copy and pasting, then you're all set to go and you may disregard the better safe than sorry. Did you try the "File"->...method instead of importing? I've tried both ways, but have not been able to successfully duplicate your error.