# Why do existing imported projects not run in my Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, import

I have purchased [this](http://p2p.wrox.com/book-beginning-android-application-development-631/) book called Beginning Android Programming and the code for all the projects in the book is made available online to everyone over [here](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Beginning-Android-Application-Development.productCd-1118017110,descCd-DOWNLOAD.html)

Now when I import any of the projects downloaded from Wrox's website (the second link), I get an multiple errors at different lines, all of which stating that some or the other object can't be resolved

Here's a shot of the errors :
[image: http://imageshack.us/f/708/errorzq.png/]

Can anyone please tell me how do I get these projects running?

Comment: Too much work. Plus that link will die one day.  This site exists to provide help for others in the future as much as you today.  Want to post the error here?

Comment: Have you set up everything? Sdk, emulator etc?

Comment: Try ctrl+shift+O for the string error. The @Override error needs Java1.6 and the Activity error needs you to install the Android SDK

Answer (score 1):

Look my answer to this thread...[Copying an Android Project Folder is Not a FULL Backup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6614103/copying-an-android-project-folder-is-not-a-full-backup/6614141#6614141)

Fix your project...

Answer (score 0):

If the fix project doesnt work try this

1. Right click at the root of your project and pick properties, then java compiler, make sure 1.6 is selected as the compiler compliance level
2. Also do the same via "Window" menu, preferences, Java, Compiler
3. Now do a clean
4. Build All

NOTE: If you still get weird errors try one more thing, get the project properties up again, select android, change the Build Target to anything earlier than you have selected, compile (does not matter if there are errors) then change it back and compile again.  I have no idea why this last step is sometimes necessary I think sometimes eclipse just wigs out and this causes a total rebuild (though you think clean would do the same thing)