# Eclipse: All my projects disappeared from Project Explorer

Tags: eclipse

It seems like all my projects (except one) disappeared from the view Project Explorer.

I'm using **Eclipse Java EE IDE** for Web Developers.
Version: **Helios Service Release 2**
Build id: 20110218-0911

Note: all the projects are present on the file system.

How to bring them back? Any ideas?

Comment: This issue seems to be still existing in Eclipse Kepler edition on Linux. All in sudden all my projects disappeared after I launched Eclipse.

Comment: Happens to me too. I post an automatic solution with a script. No more  tedious importing procedure!

Answer (score 182, accepted):

This happened to me. I'm still not sure how, but the reason was that my workspace meta data had become corrupted, probably due to Eclipse being improperly shutdown. The solution, as [explained here](http://letsgetdugg.com/2009/04/19/recovering-a-corrupt-eclipse-workspace/), is to:

Note, steps 2 & 3 are optional if Eclipse isn't crashing, but just not showing any projects.

1. Close Eclipse.
2. cd /home/user/workspace/.metadata/.plugins
3. mv  org.eclipse.core.resources org.eclipse.core.resources_bak
4. Start Eclipse
5. Do File->Import
6. General->Existing Projects into Workspace
7. Click the "Select root directory" field and browse to each subfolder in your workspace folder, and import.

For me, this was very tedious, since I had several dozen projects in my workspace, but it's the only solution I found short of restoring my entire workspace from a backup.

**Edit:** This answer is now quite old, and better solutions may now exist. Although I haven't had need to try it, I recommend attempting @antonagestam's solution first, as others have suggested it may be faster and more effective.

**Edit:** Since it's fairly simple, I'd recommend trying antonagestam's solution first. However, this problem recently re-occurred for me, and that solution did not work in my case. But neither did it interfere with this solution.

Comment: As far as I can tell, .metalog is not a subdirectory in the workspace.  Did you mean .metadata?

Also, when I go to import it says "No projects are found to import"

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. But since I have about 200 separate project-plugins, it would be too long to do this one by one. So when selecting a root directory, choose the common folder to them all and the Import dialog will find all the projects under that dir. Saved me a lot of time and nerves ;o)

Comment: Read the other answers before resorting to this... 
antonagestam's answer solved my problem in literally 2 seconds

Comment: You really should add an update to the beginning of your answer, mentioning the solution by @antonagestam below. I followed your solution first, which did nothing for me, and then his which worked (and only takes a second to do). I'm sure a lot of people will see your solution and try it without reading other answers, so it would be a useful addition.

Comment: In my case your answer solved the problem. Setting Top Level Elements -> Projects had nothing to do with it.

Comment: @Cerin - rm -rf in windows simply means delete the folder ?

Comment: Your answer was awesome ! saved a lot of my work...
No need to go through each subfolder. Just select root directory as workspace and it gets all the projects automatically. Select All is already checked
Just press 'Finished' then and u r set

Comment: I just need to chime in to say thank you for this answer.  I followed every step exactly and all my projects were restored (I almost had a panic attack when they disappeared this morning!).  Thank you!

Comment: After I import the projects they almost immediately (a couple of seconds later) disappear again. O_o Has anyone experiences such issue? I really don't want to delete my entire workspace and create it again but this seems as the only solution right now. I'm using Eclipse LUNA and it seems that this issue has not been solved for almost 4 years or maybe more. If I wasn't forced to work with Eclipse I would have dumped it long ago...

Comment: The solution provided by @antonagestam didn't work for me. However, note that you don't need to re-import each project separately; after you select the root directory of your workspace, Eclipse automatically finds all projects inside that directory.

Comment: Worked for me.I manually deleted org.eclipse.core.resources and it worked

Comment: Steps 2 and 3 were crucial for me. I couldn't import a project that I have imported before. It stayed grey on my import list until I did steps 2 and 3. It cleaned my workspace and let me import all projects in my workspace cleanly again finally!!!!

Comment: This is a bug in Eclipse. In my case, Project Explorer contains only a subset of the projects that Package Explorer contains. It should not be possible for such an inconsistency to exist.

Comment: I am using Eclipse Luna, still didn't found any better solution, just need to import them one by one.

Comment: The "edits" to this answer should be on the top of the answer so one does not do the steps and at the end realize that there was a better/faster way to solve the problem (that was not the accepted answer).

Comment: You just saved my life! I had just lost access to all my project, having branches with 300+ commits not pushed

Comment: For those who are trying to find @antonagestam's answer its in the second page of answers.. And the problem I had was that my network sandbox was inaccessible, but eclipse told me .project was missing. So, fixing my network sandbox, fixed it for me

Answer (score 85):

I had the same problem in Aptana, all of a sudden my projects were gone. Solved it by going to the drop-down menu in Project Explorer and going Top Level Elements -> Projects.

Comment: This should probably be the accepted answer. Old problem, but the most upvoted question here is just a long and unnecessary work around.

Comment: This fixed my problem - much easier than the most upvoted answer

Comment: While I'm sure there are other causes of this particular problem, following the accepted answer solution did nothing for me. This was what I needed to do.

Comment: Went through the tedious process of resetting my password just so I could upvote this answer and publicly proclaim the sheer amount of "hurrrrr" I experienced when realising the solution was this easy.

Comment: @devJunk: Well, I'd agree that this solution is much faster than the accepted answer and should probably be *tried* first. However, it's not a solution, at least in my case - and presumably not op's either. This is a solution to a silly mistake made by the developer. One that **cannot** be fixed by the accepted answer, so it's not a work-around. Sometimes you have to accept the only person who can truly determine the correct solution is the op.

Comment: This problem just re-occurred for me, and this solution didn't work. Top Level Elements -> Projects was already selected in fact.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Would the "Stackoverflow way" be to add this to the accepted answer as a first step? :)

Comment: Probably every viable unique answer here should probably be consolidated into a check list of "Things you try *before* you do this...". But, if you'll notice, @Cerin recommends your solution as just that. I'm not nitpicking your answer rather the idea an outsider can gleam what fixes op's problem. :)

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Cool, I hadn't noticed! Just wanted to know your opinion on how one "should" use SO. :)

Comment: Did not work for me, either.  Workspace crash/ incomplete shutdown in Luna.

Comment: I just got this problem myself after my computer crashed. This does not work for my. I going to try the accepted answer now

Comment: Had the same problem with Eclipse Mars, this solution did not work, I assume the workspace "crashed" and is not recoverable.

Comment: Worked for me with Eclipse 2019-06

Comment: It didn't work for me on 2021-12 (4.22.0). However, selecting Project Presentation as Flat, revealed all my projects that had vanished from view. Still investigating how to get back to my normal view.

Comment: I had the same issue and this solution did not work for me while the one from @Cerin did.

Answer (score 33):

Go to

> File --> Import --> General --> Existing Project into Workspace

Then, 
In `Root Directory` Enter the workspace path where all your projects saved & click refresh as below

[image]

And Click Finish

[image]

Comment: I think answer by @logan should have been the top answer! As suggested one can import (without copy) multiple projects at one shot. Saved my day.

Comment: @Manglesh : Cheers. Welcome :)

Comment: Worked for me when top-level elements didn't.

Comment: Thank you. This worked for me too on Eclipse 2020-12 (4.18.0)

Answer (score 15):

I was having the same problem for Android projects in Eclipse. [This](http://s0n1c2122.blogspot.com/2013/02/missing-projects-in-eclipse-workspace.html) link was very helpful in restoring the missing projects.

1. Go to 'File->Import->General->From Existing Project'.
2. Select the root folder to the Workspace.
3. Click on the 'Refresh' button.
4. Select the required projects and click 'Finish' button.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 13):

Click on Windows > Open Perspectives > java
, Press Ok. Project Explore will come back on screen..

Comment: This may be a solution for the problem "my Project Explorer has disappeared". However, the original question describes a problem where Project Explorer is on the screen, but does not contain any projects.

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem in **Luna**,
 Suddenly my projects were gone in start-up.
I solved this by select **Deselect working set** option in the drop-down menu in Project Explorer.

Note: I post this answer even this is not a right answer for this question.
Since I search for Luna and came here, while trying with discussed things I found this solution. This may help others.

Comment: Didn't work for me. I'm also experiencing this issue in Luna. However I have discovered that for some unknown reason Eclipse has selected "Working sets" as "Top Level Elements" (same menu in the Project Explorer but the first option).

Comment: Had the exact same issue in Luna, this solution worked perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

My solution is
open view menu and select "Top Level Elements" and set "Projects"

Comment: yes, this works for me! when eclipse did not shutdown, this would have been changed somehow. I was getting a glimpse of my project folders, when eclipse comes up, but would soon vanish. And yes, this was the quick fix !!

Answer (score 3):

Mona is correct - Make sure that you have the task list set to show **ALL** as the image shows.  Click the arrow to the left of the project if you want to re-factor your filter.  Reset your perspective if you do not see the task list.

[image: show all projects in eclipse]

Comment: If this worked for you please accept as answer, thanks.  You have not accepted any answers yet.

Answer (score 3):

If any of the previous methods don't work for you then delete your old workspace, create a new workspace and put it by default. You can do this by launching Eclipse twice - the second time it asks you for the workspace ;).  Then re-import all your projects there and say "problem, goodbye".

Comment: If you're restoring your project files from a backup from another system, it may be necessary to re-instate read permissions first, eg: sudo chmod a+rwx /Users/myname/workspace/*

Comment: i didn't know about it... well I have never done that but thanks for share

Answer (score 3):

Today 22-03-2016, I check again this question and using `ECLIPSE MARS` I solved with:

- Having Eclipse opened, go on **FILE** -> **RESTART**

Go on same workspace and I have all project on "PROJECT EXPLORER"

Sometime also this operation, will solve (Clicking on Projects dor see all project!!)

[image: my problem]

So Other solution is:

[image: SOLUTION]

Comment: also make sure that button 'Focus on active task' is not pushed in the Project Explorer

Answer (score 2):

if you use the "Task List" view of Eclipse, it will sometimes try to hide files or projects that it thinks are not associated with a given task (i.e. any file that was not opened while you had a certain task selected as the current task). If you want Eclipse to stop hiding files
in that case, you can just delete all tasks.

Or you may also  restart your eclipse and by just closing the project and then opening it again (from the right mouse click context menu) the files will be restored.

If that doesnt get your projects back then check the "filters option"  (Click on right corner of Project Explorer tab and open context menu. Select Filters option from menu) and make sure that your projects type isnt checked.

Comment: I deleted all of my task in "task list" and restarted Eclipse...but  still the same problem. There are no filters that could hide any of my projects. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: maybe try deleting your workspace/.metadata directory, and back up your projects for example, create a Zip file  then use it to import your existing projects into the workspace.

Comment: Are they visible in the Navigator View?

Answer (score 2):

you should check the active Working Set - make sure it is off.

Answer (score 1):

When this happened to me I had somehow set the Project Explorer to only display Working Sets. I had none, so nothing was displayed.

To fix it, I went to the Project Explorer View Menu (next to the Minimize and Maximize icons in the Project Explorer), Top Level Elements -> Projects.

Thanks to @antonagestam for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

It seems it happens to us all. I was happily hacking away at javascript, nowhere near all the nasty hibernate java stuff, and boom, "cant find org.jboss.logging.BasicLoging".
I havent touched anything!.
After an hour or so of trying to make that appear, restarting servers, mysql, eclipse, adding jars that weren't needed before,I deployed the fix all solution, the off button.
Then zap, no project.
(I am still none the wiser as to why calling Configuration() should now require jboss-logging...jar, maybe I needed it all along for when bad things happen)

My input is

1. use git, keep as little of your stuff in the eclipse workspace area as possible. Then just import project from existing git repo when eclipse loses it's marbles.
2. I also lost my server config. it's there but eclipse insists there no server config  stuff and bombs. So make another one, I've expressed my feelings about eclipse in my new server name, and copy your apache xml configs (workspace/Servers/I_Love_Eclipse) over from the original perfectly good directory.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how/why, but this happened to me once when I added a task to Mylyn. Seemed that mylyn was filtering my projects. When I deleted the task they all came back.

Answer (score 1):

None of the answers provided here worked for me. My Enterprise Explorer was completely grey and I couldn't even import or reimport projects.

In my .metadata.log I saw this error:

```
assertion failed: working set with same name already registered
```

So I deleted these file:

.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.ui.workbench\workingsets.xml

Now I can see all my projects. I didn't have to add them back again.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution that worked better for me.  Under my home folder I found a workspace/.metadata folder.  I copied this folder into my eclipse workspace, replacing the .metadata folder that had been there.  When I started Eclipse everything was back to the way I had left it - all projects present, all open files were still open, etc.  Just like nothing had happened! I'm using Neon.

Comment: This helped me a lot. First I made a backup from the .metadata folder, copied the folder from another (similar) workspace and overwrote this folder and file from my backup:
1. .metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\
2. .metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.settings\org.eclipse.wst.server.core.prefs

Answer (score 1):

As a preliminary (before reimporting everything), here is a solution to recover working sets in which project were (if any).

I had more than 100 projects and each was in one of 14 working sets.
If your top level elements changes (accidentaly or not if it is a bug) from "Working set" to "Projects", you only see projects that are NOT in a working set, and if, as I do, you don't have any projects outside a working set, you think all is lost because you cannot see anything (blank package explorer).
So the solution is now obvious: click on the top left small white triangle MENU, than select "Top level elements", than select "Working sets".
You also have the possibility to rearrange the working sets list items.
Hope it helps
Unfortunatly the working sets were empty after the recovery, but at least I
recovered their names.

Config: Eclipse Oxygen.2 Release (4.7.2) with Java 1.8 on Windows 10.

Comment: This solved my case where I open a freshly installed Eclipse pointing to existing workspace, and I open "Pydev Package Explorer" and only see "Java {Main, Test} Sources" while I should see many existing projects.

Answer (score 1):

Got this issue on returning to an Eclipse project on a VM after leaving it untouched for maybe a couple of weeks.

I started to apply the accepted answer, but when I got to the step of renaming the folder and had exited Eclipse, I saw there was an instance of Eclipse still running. I realized Windows had for some reason started a second instance of Eclipse when I hit the taskbar button. The second instance had been unable to access the workspace while the first instance was using it.

Once I undid my folder rename, and closed and restarted the original instance of Eclipse, I was able to use File->Switch Workspace to get my normal workspace back.

Answer (score 0):

Solution that Cerin provide, importing each time that this problem happens, could be boring.

So I've implemented a script that control if workspace setting exits: if not, restore it to default.

I have an eclipse shortcut icon on the top panel that execute:

```
 /opt/eclipse/checkWorkspace && /opt/eclipse/eclipse
```

Script **checkWorkspace** is the seguent:

```
#!/bin/bash

ECLIPSE_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/eclipse/configuration"
ECLIPSE_CONFIG_FILE="config.ini"
ECLIPSE_CONFIG_SETTING="osgi.instance.area.default"
DEFAULT_WORKSPACE_PATH="@user.home/workspace"
ECLIPSE_LOG="/var/log/eclipse.log"

cd ${ECLIPSE_CONFIG_PATH}

function sedeasy {
  sed -i "s/$(echo $1 | sed -e 's/\([[\/.*]\|\]\)/\\&/g')/$(echo $2 | sed -e 's/[\/&]/\\&/g')/g" $3
}

WORKSPACE_EXISTS=$(cat ${ECLIPSE_CONFIG_FILE} | grep ${ECLIPSE_CONFIG_SETTING})

# If workspace setting doesn't exists 
if [ -z "$WORKSPACE_EXISTS" ]; then
  echo "worskspace setting not exists, resetting to default." >> ${ECLIPSE_LOG}
  newConf=${ECLIPSE_CONFIG_SETTING}"="${DEFAULT_WORKSPACE_PATH}
  echo ${newConf} >> ${ECLIPSE_CONFIG_FILE}     
else    
   # if setting exist but it is empty
   vals=(${WORKSPACE_EXISTS//=/ }) 
   length=$(echo ${#vals[@]})
   if [ "${length}" -lt 2 ]; then
       newConf=${ECLIPSE_CONFIG_SETTING}"="${DEFAULT_WORKSPACE_PATH}
       confToReplace=$(echo ${vals[0]})
       sedeasy ${confToReplace} ${newConf} ${ECLIPSE_CONFIG_FILE}
       echo "worskspace exists but is empty, resetting to default." >> ${ECLIPSE_LOG}
   else
      echo "Worskspace already set:" "${vals[1]}"
   fi
fi
```

Maybe could be semplified, but works.

Answer (score 0):

I tried many solutions. I found mine in the drop down menu of the Entreprise Explorer:
- Deleting org.eclipse.core.resources has no effect.
- "Top Level Elements -> Projects" was already checked for me; swtiching with Documents has no effect. 
- Selecting all extensions in the filter option of the drop down menu has no effect at first sight, maybe it solve part of the problem.

The solution come from "Unselecting documents" (third choice in the Entreprise Explorer drop down menu). I think that choice reset the filtering of documents displayed in the Explorer.

Hope it'll helps
JN Gerbaux

Answer (score 0):

Tedious but it worked for me (Kepler):

1. Using the OS zip utility, zip everything below the project workspace folder to a zip file, to be placed in a separate directory (will use `c:\tmp\workspace.zip` as an example).
2. Unzip `workspace.zip` to the `c:\tmp` directory.  Assume there's a project folder called `Project1`

   a.  Ensure all the files in `Project1` have *Full Control* permissions for *Everyone* or at least `777` permissions.
3. Remove all the project folders in the Eclipse workspace.
4. Recreate each project one by one according to its original type (Java, Dynamic Web, etc.).  (Will use `Project1` as an example.)  Do **not** add anything.
5. In Eclipse, do *File -> Import -> File System*.  Then select `c:\tmp\Project1` as a source
6. Select the workspace *Project1* as a destination.  Do **not** overwrite any file.
7. In Eclipse, refresh the project and test it.  It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Also had this Problem.

My Solution was to uncheck the Box PyDev: Closed Projects, even if those hidden Projects are PHP and NOT Python Projects. (Strange BUG in Eclipse/Aptana???)

Be aware that even "Closed Projects" (a Topic above *Pydev closed projects*) is also unchecked. So you have to ***uncheck both*** Settings.

this: [eclipse shows only "open projects" in project explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26295286/eclipse-shows-only-open-projects-in-project-explorer)

Answer (score 0):

All of my projects were closed and I had hid the closed projects in the settings. 
So to open projects go to top right view menu, and uncheck Closed Projects option. Assuming it is checked already.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do the following steps

```
         File --> Import --> Existing Projects into Workspace

         Select the root directory as ur old root folder

         Finish.
```

Yahoo.. There is ur old projects again in ur project explorer

Answer (score 0):

1) File > import > Existing projects into workspace 
2) Choose your workspace folder
3) select all of your projects 
4) finish

All are OK with above way !!!

Answer (score 0):

File - Import - Existing projects into workspace - browse - choose your workspase - done!

Answer (score 0):

If Eclipse was killed during a shutdown, the projects database may become corrupted (the project database is normally located in:  `workspace/.metadata/org.eclipse.core.resources/.root/1.tree`).

A message like this will be logged in `Workspace/.metadata/.log`:

`!MESSAGE Could not read metadata for '.../.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.root/.markers'.`

The data is lost. You need to import your projects again (File->Import ->
General->Existing Projects into Workspace).

The list of projects that were in the workspace can still be seen in `.metadata/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects/`.

Projects located outside the workspace will have a `.location` file with the path to the project.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem.

file>restart.
Projects and modules appeared after restarting the eclipse, but faced new error; 
*An internal error occurred during: "AppXray Indexing...". java.lang.NullPointerException.*

So it's good to be on safe side, import the project again in a new workspace.

Answer (score 0):

if you go to *Quick Access* and type in *Projects* you will get it your projects back.

Answer (score 0):

Choose
    *File > Switch Workspace> 'MyWorkSpace'*

Eclipse restarts and if you are as lucky as me, the projects are mapped correctly.

---

In my case I have the developer environment on a shared server with about 10-15 users that may accidentally change things that affects other users.

*Tip of the day:*  **Don't do that...**

Answer (score 0):

I had this trouble recently, but in my case I hid all items by myself when check all items in "Filters and Сustomization" dialog.

I just didn't read note on top of them, and had thought that checks will allow TO SEE any additional items in Project Explorer. But in reality, checking that checks HIDE corresponding items from Explorer!

Please note this! )

Dialog:

[image: dialog]

way to open this dialog:

[image: way to open this dialog]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue , after Mac update , Eclipse would show the parent project folder , nothing under it , and unable to import project into existing workspace , it used to give message saying "Project already exists in workspace" , what worked for me was to click on the parent folder and select import , then existing projects into workplace , then point to your folder , you don't need to click next , close the window and right click on the parent folder and select open project , took some time , and the project was back .

Answer (score -1):

I tried differently for the same issue and worked .

Go to your project location in hard drive. ex: /home/user/workspace/project/settings and
Delete this file org.eclipse.core.resources.prefs

For full details check out bellow link

http://errorkode.com/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=8&sid=40cff1661bf0ace12878d6d6fb7e75ac