# eclipse shows only "open projects" in project explorer

Tags: eclipse, aptana

**System:**

```
Eclipse Standard/SDK
Version: Luna Release (4.4.0)
Build id: 20140612-0600

Aptana Plugin 3.6.0.
```

**Problem:**

In PHP-Explorer I see all my Projects in Workspace.
In Project Explorer, I only see current open Projects.

So I check the setting in "Customize view". 
[image]

The Setting is set to "show" all closed Project, but they don't.

[image]

Any Idea, how to got my closed Project shown there?

Comment: See also: [Eclipse Mars - imported projects don't show up in Project/Enterprise Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45465437/4561887)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the Problem.

A bit below the Checkbox "Closed projects" there is a Checkbox "PyDev closed projects". I've uncheck this Box and Projects are visible again.

Seems to be a Bug, cause this aren't Python Projects?!

I have createt an issue on aptana-bugtracker: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-8332

Answer (score 2):

The issue got resolved (Eclipse Mars) when i changed the "Top Level Elements" drop down value to "Projects". It was set to "Working Sets" previously.

[image]