# Eclipse project explorer empty

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu-14.04

on ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Eclipse 3.8.1 builid id :debbuild

Almost everytime I open Eclipse, the project explorer list is empty and I have to re-import following the instructions from the accepted answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10542974/2472097

Is anyone else suffering from this? Is there a way for eclipse to remember my projects?

Answer (score 1):

Create a new workspace (File -> Switch workspace) and import projects there. Your workspace might have been corrupted beyond what clearing org.eclipse.core.resources could fix.

Comment: Thanks. Tried it and so far so good. Will let you know if it survives.

Comment: I just booted up my machine this morning and the project explorer is empty.

Answer (score 0):

When shutting down the ubuntu vm, don't simply use the X on the upper right corner and choose power off, which is similar to pulling the power cable in a real system.
Instead, choose power off/log out from the menu on the upper right corner (many have different items depends on ubuntu version) and it should give you the choices of suspend/power off, and choosing power off will give you the choices of restart or power off.  Turning off this way give the system a chance to gracefully shutdown and save its state.