# Preventing projects from getting disappeared from Eclipse Project Explorer

Tags: eclipse

I've come across this issue so many times irrespective of whether I close eclipse properly or not. I mean, I can understand if the projects disappear if you fail to the close eclipse properly or if it crashes. But even when I close eclipse properly, below issue occurs.

**Issue**: I create a project in eclipse and work on it. When I'm done, I close eclipse and when I open eclipse after sometime (or after some days) using the same workspace, the project is disappeared from the Project Explorer. I will update with snapshots once I'm able to replicate the issue again.

I was able to recover my projects using the steps provided in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17176548/5118106) answer, but I'm curious if there is any preventive measure/steps that can be followed to avoid this issue in the future so that I need not import my projects every time I open eclipse.

Comment: That's obviously not normal behavior. Can you give more details about this? Have you tried creating a whole new workspace, importing your projects into it, then shutting down and restarting Eclipse?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Yes, usually when this issue happens I create a new workspace in the name of the disappeared workspace and when I restart eclipse, they appear in the Project Explorer. I was just wondering if there is any permanent solution to prevent this from happening everytime,

Comment: It's still not clear (to me) what you're experiencing and what, specifically, you're doing. Are you saying that when you shut down and later restart Eclipse, the entire workspace is gone (note that Eclipse will re-create a new workspace if it doesn't find one in the location you choose at start-up)? Are you even getting prompted to select your workspace at Eclipse startup? Please provide as detailed a description of what you're doing and seeing as possible. Like I said, it's not normal at all for Eclipse to have "memory loss."

Comment: 1) Are you saying that when you shut down and later restart Eclipse, the entire workspace is gone? -- Yes, the entire workspace disappears from Project Explorer.
2) Are you even getting prompted to select your workspace at Eclipse startup? -- Yes and I use a SINGLE workspace for all the projects I create in my PC.
Yes I too understand it's not normal for Eclipse to have "memory loss." and that's why I'm curious if anyone else have this issue and Is there any solution for this?